# Minted formatting of python source from a file newtcbinputlisting

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I am typesetting a document with python scripts, some are inline and some are sourced from files under folder scripts. I am using tcolorbox with minted, and for testing I tried formatting both inline scripts and from one file scripts/hello.py.

Requirement: These two scripts share a common counter defined under newtcblisting programBox.

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./pythonBookFiles/pythonBookImages/} }
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf.,jpg}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ %
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=maroon,%
    filecolor=maroon,%
    linkcolor=maroon,%
    urlcolor=maroon,%
    hidelinks,% 
    %   pdftitle=\thetitle, 
    %   pdfauthor=\theauthor,
    linktoc=all
}

\usepackage[many,minted]{tcolorbox}% version 3.03 or better

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
    \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style={minted language=#2,minted options={#3}}}}

\mynewminted{mypython}{python}{tabsize=2,linenos=false,         numbersep=4pt, fontsize=\footnotesize}


\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section,
list inside=mypyg]{programBox}[3][]{%
    listing only,title={Program \thetcbcounter: #3},
    list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#3},
    enhanced,colframe=orange!70!black,breakable, drop fuzzy shadow, myminted/#2,#1}



\newtcbinputlisting[use counter from=programBox]{\programFile}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    title=Program. (\thetcbcounter) of \texttt{#2},
    colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing only,breakable,#1}




\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{mypyg}{\addvspace{10pt}}}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@tcolorbox{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}    
    

\section{Structure of Python program}

A simple program is shown as \ref{prog:simple}


\begin{programBox}{mypython,label=prog:simple}{Python Program }
    import os, django.contrib
    #this is one line comment 
    
    """
    This is 
    Multi line 
    Comment 
    """
    
    int a 
    print(a)
\end{programBox}



\section{Python source from a file}

\programFile[before upper=\textit{This is the included file content:}]{scripts/hello.py}


\end{document}
```

Till programBox environment it was working fine, but with \programFile macro it is failing to compile.

The error I got was Package minted **Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. ...ncluded file content:}]{scripts/hello.py}** But the pygments is installed. Please help me to input files. Thanks in advance.

The following test file is under folder scripts with filename: hello.py

```
import os, django.contrib

print("hello World")
```

Comment: Your example compiles here. If in the output of `programBox` env, code is highlighted, then your pygments is successfully installed. Does the `hello.py` reside in subdir `scripts`?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried now again with a fresh subdir with scripts and hello.py, but no success.  Anyhow I am using minted only, without tcolorbox.  My requirement was to share counter with program and program-file and have a \listofprograms in memoir class. With minted I am able to do that, so for time being it is sufficient. Thanks once again.